# receiving default values on Post instead of actual values

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, postman

I'm new to Spring Boot. I'm currently working on a post request which is returning my defaultValues instead of the actual values I'm passing in the postman body. Your help is greatly appreciated in this manner. Below, I have copied the Controller, Model, the file where I am running my application, and the Respository.

```
Json dict that I'm passing into postman
{   
    "email": "Katie",
    "pass": "UnicornPoop",
    "city": "",
    "hairstyleType": "color"
}
```

```
    package com.example.Cosmo.Budget.Tracker.controllers;
    import com.example.Cosmo.Budget.Tracker.Models.WebUser;
    import com.example.Cosmo.Budget.Tracker.WebUserRepository;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
    
    
    @RestController
    
    public class CosmoController {
        //webUserRepository is an instance variable that allows me to access the records in my table.
        // WebUserRepository is the class/interface that communicates with Database/Table
        @Autowired
        private WebUserRepository webUserRepository;
    
        @PostMapping("/addusers")
        public String addWebUser(@RequestParam(value ="email", defaultValue = "user1") String email,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "pass", defaultValue="Rih") String pass,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "hairstyleType", defaultValue="shampoo")String hairstyleType,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "city", defaultValue="Tampa")String city
        )
        {
            WebUser webUser = new WebUser();
            webUser.setUsername(email);
            webUser.setPassword(pass);
            webUser.setCity(city);
            webUser.setHairstyle(hairstyleType);
            webUserRepository.save(webUser);
            return "Added new users to repo!";
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/getusers")
        public Iterable<WebUser> getWebUser() {
            return webUserRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

```
package com.example.Cosmo.Budget.Tracker.Models;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
  @Entity
    public class WebUser {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String email;
        private String pass;
        private String hairstyleType;
        private String city;
    
    
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public WebUser(String email,
                       String pass,
                       String hairstyleType,
                       String city
        )
        {
            this.email = email;
            this.pass = pass;
            this.hairstyleType = hairstyleType;
            this.city = city;
        }
    
        public WebUser(){
    
        }
    
        public String getUsername() {
            return email;
        }
    
        public void setUsername(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return pass;
        }
    
        public void setPassword(String pass) {
            this.pass = pass;
        }
    
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }
        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }
        
        public String getHairstyle() {
            return hairstyleType;
        }
        public void setHairstyle(String hairstyleType) {
            this.hairstyleType = hairstyleType;
        }
    
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
    
            return "webUser{" +
                    "id=" + id +
                    ", username='" + email + '\'' +
                    ", password='" + pass + '\'' +
                    ", hairstyleType='" + hairstyleType + '\'' +
                    ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

```
package com.example.Cosmo.Budget.Tracker;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class CosmoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CosmoApplication.class, args);

    }
```

```
package com.example.Cosmo.Budget.Tracker;
import com.example.Cosmo.Budget.Tracker.Models.WebUser;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface WebUserRepository extends CrudRepository<WebUser, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the details you posted,

In postman, as you see you are posting details in **request body** as json.

But in code, you are trying to retrieve them in **query parameters**.

Expected: `POST http://.../addusers?email=s@s.com&pass=y...`

I would suggest you to create a java class in your code and use `@RequestBody` to retrieve all these fields.

Example at:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body#@requestbody